# Separate compiling a .cu file, .c file and main.cpp file and linking together using a makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, undefined

This is how my makefile looks like, I have seperata cudaex.cu cudaaex.h plotter.c plotter.h and mainfn.cpp files. I compiled and created .o files separately. But I cant link them and make an executable file. If further informations needed I can post other codes also.

```
CUDA ?= /usr/local/cuda
CUDA_LIB :=-L $(CUDA)/lib64 -L $(CUDA)/lib -L /usr/lib64/nvidia -L /usr/lib/nvidia
CUDA_INC += -I $(CUDA)/include

program_INCLUDE_DIRS := ./src
program_LIBRARY_DIRS :=

LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))

LDFLAGS  += $(CUDA_LIB) -L $(CUDA)/lib64 
LIBS     += -lcudart -lcuda -lpthread -ldl



CC      = gcc
NCC     = nvcc
CPP     = g++
CFLAGS  = -O3 -I./src
RM      = rm -f



program_OBJS:= gnuplot_i.o cudaex.o plotter.o mainfn.o



default:    gnuplot_i.o cudaex.o plotter.o mainfn.o all

gnuplot_i.o:    src/gnuplot_i.c src/gnuplot_i.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o gnuplot_i.o src/gnuplot_i.c

cudaex.o: 
    $(NCC) -c -o cudaex.o cudaex.cu

plotter.o:  plotter.c gnuplot_i.o plotter.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o plotter.o plotter.c

mainfn.o:   mainfn.cpp cudaex.h plotter.h plotter.o gnuplot_i.o
    $(CPP) -c -o mainfn.o mainfn.cpp



all: mainfn

mainfn: $(program_OBJS)
        g++ $(program_OBJS) -o mainfn $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)


clean:
    $(RM) gnuplot_i.o cudaex.o plotter.o mainfn.o mainfn
```

[this is the output of the make command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdYeA.png)

Comment: Where is `graphplots` supposed to come from?

Comment: Please try moving $(program_OBJS) after '-o mainfn'.

Comment: Its the function inside the plotter.c

Comment: The linker complains that it cannot find `graphplots` in `plotter.o` nor anywhere else. We cannot diagnose the problem with the information you have given; I suggest you try a simpler program, one that requires one or two source files, not four, and build it *without* Make, before attempting to do so *with* Make.